# Cast to Embedded failed error in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

I've been looking for solving my problem in many sources but unfortunately I can't find an answer. Can you help me please.

There is file with schema in it.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config/database');

const analogueNumberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    analogueName: String,
    analogueNum: String
});

const detailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    detailName: String,
    originalNumber: [String],
    analogueNumber: [analogueNumberSchema],
    note: String,
    picture: String
});

const modelModificationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    modelModificationName: String,
    modelDetails: {
        engine: [detailSchema],
        transmission: [detailSchema],
        frontAxle: [detailSchema],
        rearAxle: [detailSchema],
        breakes: [detailSchema],
        electrics: [detailSchema]
    }
});

const markModelsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    markModelName: String,
    modelModifications: [modelModificationsSchema]
});

const carsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    markName: String,
    markModels: [markModelsSchema]
});

const Car = module.exports = new mongoose.model('Car', carsSchema);

module.exports.addCar = function (newCar, callback) {
    newCar.save(callback);
};
```

Here is the router code:

```
router.post('/post', (req, res, next) => {
let newCar = new Car({
    markName: req.body.markName,
    markModels: [{
        markModelName: req.body.markModelName,
        modelModifications: [{
            modelModificationName: req.body.modelModificationName,
            modelDetails: [{
                engine: [{
                    detailName: req.body.detailName,
                    originalNumber: req.body.originalNumber.split(","),
                    analogueNumber: [{
                        analogueName: req.body.analogueName,
                        analogueNum: req.body.analogueNumber
                    }],
                    note: req.body.note,
                    picture: req.body.picture
                }],
                transmission: [{
                    detailName: req.body.detailName,
                    originalNumber: req.body.originalNumber.split(","),
                    analogueNumber: [{
                        analogueName: req.body.analogueName,
                        analogueNum: req.body.analogueNumber
                    }],
                    note: req.body.note,
                    picture: req.body.picture
                }],
                frontAxle: [{
                    detailName: req.body.detailName,
                    originalNumber: req.body.originalNumber.split(","),
                    analogueNumber: [{
                        analogueName: req.body.analogueName,
                        analogueNum: req.body.analogueNumber
                    }],
                    note: req.body.note,
                    picture: req.body.picture
                }],
                rearAxle: [{
                    detailName: req.body.detailName,
                    originalNumber: req.body.originalNumber.split(","),
                    analogueNumber: [{
                        analogueName: req.body.analogueName,
                        analogueNum: req.body.analogueNumber
                    }],
                    note: req.body.note,
                    picture: req.body.picture
                }],
                breakes: [{
                    detailName: req.body.detailName,
                    originalNumber: req.body.originalNumber.split(","),
                    analogueNumber: [{
                        analogueName: req.body.analogueName,
                        analogueNum: req.body.analogueNumber
                    }],
                    note: req.body.note,
                    picture: req.body.picture
                }],
                electrics: [{
                    detailName: req.body.detailName,
                    originalNumber: req.body.originalNumber.split(","),
                    analogueNumber: [{
                        analogueName: req.body.analogueName,
                        analogueNum: req.body.analogueNumber
                    }],
                    note: req.body.note,
                    picture: req.body.picture
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
});

Car.addCar(newCar, (err, car) => {
    if (err) {
        res.json({success: false, msg: 'failed to add new car'});
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.json({success: true, msg: 'new car added'});
    }
});
});
```

Here is the code of post-query in "Postman"

```
{
"markName": "Daewoo",
"markModels": [{
    "markModelName": "Nexia",
    "modelModifications": [{
        "modelModificationName": "1.5 8v",
        "modelDetails": [{
            "engine":[{
                "detailName": "fdkj",
                "originalNumber": ["123", "4545"],
                "analogueNumber": [{
                    "analogueName": "sdkfd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfs"
                },
                {
                    "analogueName": "sdd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfsasdas"
                }],
                "note": "csdsldkf;sks;dskjfsndjfns",
                "picture": ""
            }],
          "transmission": [{
                "detailName": "fdkj",
                "originalNumber": ["123", "4545"],
                "analogueNumber": [{
                    "analogueName": "sdkfd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfs"
                },
                {
                    "analogueName": "sdd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfsasdas"
                }],
                "note": "csdsldkf;sks;dskjfsndjfns",
                "picture": ""
            }],
          "frontAxle": [{
                "detailName": "fdkj",
                "originalNumber": ["123", "4545"],
                "analogueNumber": [{
                    "analogueName": "sdkfd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfs"
                },
                {
                    "analogueName": "sdd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfsasdas"
                }],
                "note": "csdsldkf;sks;dskjfsndjfns",
                "picture": ""
            }],
          "rearAxle": [{
                "detailName": "fdkj",
                "originalNumber": ["123", "4545"],
                "analogueNumber": [{
                    "analogueName": "sdkfd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfs"
                },
                {
                    "analogueName": "sdd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfsasdas"
                }],
                "note": "csdsldkf;sks;dskjfsndjfns",
                "picture": ""
            }],
          "breakes": [{
                "detailName": "fdkj",
                "originalNumber": ["123", "4545"],
                "analogueNumber": [{
                    "analogueName": "sdkfd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfs"
                },
                {
                    "analogueName": "sdd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfsasdas"
                }],
                "note": "csdsldkf;sks;dskjfsndjfns",
                "picture": ""
            }],
          "electrics": [{
                "detailName": "fdkj",
                "originalNumber": ["123", "4545"],
                "analogueNumber": [{
                    "analogueName": "sdkfd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfs"
                },
                {
                    "analogueName": "sdd",
                    "analogueNum": "csdfsasdas"
                }],
                "note": "csdsldkf;sks;dskjfsndjfns",
                "picture": ""
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
 }
```

And there is the error message:

> 'Cast to Embedded failed for value "[ { engine: [ [Object] ],\n
>   transmission: [ [Object] ],\n    frontAxle: [ [Object] ],\n
>   rearAxle: [ [Object] ],\n    breakes: [ [Object] ],\n    electrics: [
>   [Object] ] } ]" at path "modelDetails"',
>           name: 'CastError',
>           stringValue: '"[ { engine: [ [Object] ],\n    transmission: [ [Object] ],\n    frontAxle: [ [Object] ],\n    rearAxle: [ [Object]
>   ],\n    breakes: [ [Object] ],\n    electrics: [ [Object] ] } ]"',
>           kind: 'Embedded',
>           value: [Array],
>           path: 'modelDetails',
>           reason: [Object] } },   _message: 'Car validation failed',   name: 'ValidationError' }

I'm very appreciate of your help. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At last i have an answer of my problem. There is mistake in roter code. All you need is just define properties whithout defining structure. Here is the code

```
router.post('/post', (req, res, next) => {
let newCar = new Car({
    markName: req.body.markName,
    markModels: req.body.markModels,
    modelModificationName: req.body.modelModificationName,
    modelDetails: req.body.modelDetails,
    engine: req.body.engine,
    transmission: req.body.transmission,
    frontAxle: req.body.frontAxle,
    rearAxle: req.body.rearAxle,
    breakes: req.body.breakes,
    electrics: req.body.electrics,
    detailName: req.body.detailName,
    originalNumber: req.body.originalNumber,
    analogueNumber: req.body.analogueNumber,
    note: req.body.note,
    picture: req.body.picture,
    analogueName: req.body.analogueName,
    analogueNum: req.body.analogueNum
});

Car.addCar(newCar, (err, car) => {
    if (err) {
        res.json({ success: false, msg: 'failed to add new car' });
        console.log(err);

    } else {
        res.json({ success: true, msg: 'new car added' });
    }
});
```

});
If anyone was interested, thankyou. Sorry for mistakes in text))